# Programming an Android application to switch default SIM for mobile Data

Tags: applications, adb, dual-sim, network-signal, apn

I am working on a project in which I have to switch the default SIM for data automatically, and without the need for user intervention. I read some posts on internet and got to know a method in which we can switch off one of the sim and Data will automatically be switched to secondary sim.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48696898/turning-off-second-sim-via-adb-shell-tasker-using-activities-intents

This needs Android debug bridge. But, I am not able to find any function responsible for switching default data sim.

Comment: Hi, note that app development is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users or power-users (but not necessarily developers) solving their issues. We might be able to help as far as the ADB command, but we can't help with Java API.

Comment: Switching SIMs is a privileged action. I don't think Google will happily let a non-privileged app do it without user interaction.